# How to pass parameters to PowerShell script from TFS build process?

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

I created a little PowerShell script to change connection string in my web.config.

```
param([string]$webConfigPath, [string]$connectionStringName, [string]$connectionStringValue)

# get the full path of the web config file
$webConfigFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($webConfigPath, 'Web.config')
# load the XML
$webConfig = [xml](cat $webConfigFile)

#change the appropriate config
$webConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add | foreach {
    if($_.name -eq  $connectionStringName){
        $_.connectionString = $connectionStringValue
    }
}

#save the file
$webConfig.Save($webConfigFile)
```

I added it to my build process. How to pass the build's variables to the script?

(I use the new script based build process, so I only have a builtin "Arguments" field for the parameter)

Comment: Altering your web.config should happen during the release process, not the build process.

Comment: I use the build process to put my site to the two test servers on every checkin. How to do that without build process?

Answer (score 7):

You can put all parameters in a single line into Arguments files like this:

```
-webConfigPath "c:\web.config" -connectionStringName "My connection string"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. How to pass the variables of the build process? Like BuildConfiguration and my custom attributes.

Comment: With an $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER syntax from the source code. Oh, I was stupid.