# How to pass selected arguments to Powershell script which accepts multiple argumnets in Microsoft TFS?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a script which takes arguments as

```
.\script1.ps1 -Arg1 "Argument 1" -Arg2 "Argument 2"
```

I have set the format for arguments in TFS as:

```
.\script.ps1 -Arg1 $($arg1) -Arg2 $($Arg2)
```

I get the following error when I try to pass just Arg2:

> Missing an argument for parameter 'Arg1'. Specify a parameter of type
>   'System.String[]' and  try again.

Comment: Inside the ps1 file, just change the param type to system.string like `[String]$param1'

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question for :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142045/how-to-pass-parameters-to-powershell-script-from-tfs-build-process
Which version of TFS?

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you are placing the arguments in variables. And I suspect that you just enter the value for $Arg2 variable when you try to pass just Arg2. In this scenario, the powershell script is run in the following format will the cause the error message you got since the Arg1 argument is empty:

```
.\script.ps1 -Arg1 -Arg2 Arg2Value
```

A workaround for this would be using variable to control the arguments directly. For example, add two variable in the build definition: Arg1 and Arg2
[image]

And in the PowerShell script task arguments, just enter: `$(Arg1) $(Arg2)`
[image]

With this, you can simply set the Arg1 variable to empty when queue the build if you only want to pass Arg2.